# Linked list losing all of it's values after printf()

Tags: c, linked-list

```
typedef struct list_node
{
    char* dataPtr;
    struct list_node* next;
}ListNode;

typedef struct list
{
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* tail;
}List;

void main()
{

    List lst;
    ListNode n1, n2, n3;

    lst.head = &n1;
    lst.tail = &n3;

    n1.dataPtr = "one";
    n1.next = &n2;
    n2.dataPtr = "two";
    n2.next = &n3;
    n3.dataPtr = "three";
    n3.next = NULL;

    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

While going over the code with a debugger, after the `printf()` the list loses all of it's values. Why's that?

Comment: 'Cause it goes outta scope when `main()` returns?

Comment: Ah, and because of `void main()`.

Comment: Why would it? I haven't changed or accessed anything after nor inside `printf()`

Comment: Non sequitur. It's still the last statement in `main()`...!

Answer (score 1):

The variables `lst` and their nodes are out-of-scope because your `printf` statement is the last statement in the block.

(As a side note, don't use `void main()` but use `int main()` and return 0 at the end.)

Answer (score -1):

It's working fine for me, after adding a `return 0;` at the end:

http://codepad.org/iVBNTEXn

After `printf("Hello, world!\n");` is executed, the debugger exits the scope of `main`, so your list simply no longer exists.

Comment: Doesn't really matter much what statement you put after the `printf`, `while(0);` would have worked equally well... I suspect.